# type/method resolution when using local variable vs method return value

Tags: java

I recently spoted type resolution behaviour in Java for which I'm not sure what the reason is.

First of all there was a utility class with two methods:

```
public static String quoteContent(Collection<Object> object) {
   return ...
}

publis static String quoteContent(Object object) {
   return ...
}
```

When I call quoteContent() with collection returned from a method, e.g. this way:

```
quoteContent(Arrays.asList("1",null));
```

the `quoteContent(Collection<Object>)` is called as expected.

But if I use intermediate local variable, like this:

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList();
someList.add("one");
quoteContent(someList);
```

then `quoteContent(Object)` is, a bit suprisingly, called instead - **why**?

Comment: A `List<String>` is not a `Collection<Object>`, so the `Object` overload is chosen.

Comment: With the intermediate local variable the argument to `quoteContent()` is a `List<String>`. A `List<String>` **is not** a `List<Object>` (you can add only `String`s to a `List<String>`, but you can add all kinds of objects to a `List<Object>`.) In the first example the compiler infers the result of `Arrays.asList("1",null)` as a `List<Object>`.

Comment: If I remove `QuoteContent (Object obj)`, I get a compiler error `List<String> cannot be converted to List<Object>` on `quoteContent(someList)`. If I restore it, but change `quoteContent (Collection<Object> obj)` to `quoteContent (Collection<? extends Object> obj)`, `QutoeContent (someList)` calls the method with the `Collection` argument.